# how to get first child node in realtimedatabase firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: my database in realtimedatabase]

i have tried to get this child's data only and show it in listview by substring from start word to [to] word by using `addValueEventListener` but in all way's he get an error in `onDataChange` method ...

i tried to get this data by this code

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (ds.getValue().toString().contains(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayName"))) {
                            chat_childs += ds.getValue().toString() + "\n";
                            String doctorName = chat_childs.substring(0, chat_childs.lastIndexOf("to"));
                            allDoctorsModels.add(new AllDoctorsModel(doctorName, "", ""));
                        }
                    }
                    allDoctorsAdapter = new AllDoctorsAdapter(patient_message.this,allDoctorsModels,getIntent().getStringExtra("displayName"));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(allDoctorsAdapter);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: error was in this line ` String doctorName = chat_childs.substring(0, chat_childs.lastIndexOf("to")); `

Comment: @AhmedEl-Nakib Please include the exact error message and stack trace in your question.

Comment: Was, isn't anymore? And what's the actual error? Please also responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo the error was (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Comment: @AhmedEl-Nakib Please add, as also Frank van Puffelen asked you, the exact error message and stack trace in your question and indicate the exact line at which the error occurs.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen there is no error message - the application was crash and get to me [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first child `Doc Ahmed Rafaat to Pat Ahmed El-Nakib`, do the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  String key = ds.getKey();
                  if(key.contains("Doc Ahmed Rafaat to Pat Ahmed El-Nakib")
                   {
                      String doctorName = key.subString(4,16);
                      allDoctorsModels.add(new AllDoctorsModel(doctorName, "", ""));
                   }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

First loop inside of the direct children of `chats`, then retrieve all the keys and check if the key contains `Doc Ahmed Rafaat to Pat Ahmed El-Nakib` then using `subString` on the variable `key` you can retrieve the name `Ahmed Rafaat`.

Comment: wait i'll try it

Comment: check the explanation

Comment: in my code the key is equal to `Doc Ahmed Rafaat to Pat Ahmed El-Nakib` therefore you can usee subString(4,16), but if it is equal to for example `Doc Ahmed Rafaat` then you will get an error string index out of bound exception